# How to name two variables that have the same meaning but different types

Tags: java, naming-conventions, naming

I have a method that parses a String and converts it to a boolean.
The legal values are "true" and "false".

```
boolean convertStringToBoolean(String text) {
  if (text.equals("true") {
    return true;
  } else if (text.equals("false")) {
    return false;
  } else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(text);
  }
}
```

When I use this variable, I get a naming problem.

```
void doSomething(String isSpecificReadString) {
  boolean isSpecificRead = convertStringToBoolean(isSpecificReadString);
  ...
}
```

The problem is that the parameter carries a meaning that I want to keep in its name.
The meaning doesn't change just because the type is changed.
So far, my solution has been to just suffix the type to the parameter.
But I don't like this solution.

**What should I call the variables to solve this problem?**

Comment: Define an overload `void doSomething(boolean isSpecificRead)` that you call from this method; or that you call directly, as in `doSomething(convertStringToBoolean(text))`.

Comment: This boils down to a matter of opinion, and so is off-topic for SO. Do what you think is simplest and clearest, and do it consistently, and you'll be fine.

Comment: Of course, the question is: Why does `doSomething` accept a `"true"`/`"false"` `String` in the first place?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, wrt. my question being off-topic, then I disagree. Yes, the problem is opinion based, but there are many conventions to handle naming. This topic is often discussed in Java books, making it a problem that is worthy of addressing. I present a concrete case where I ask for such a convention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As inspired by Andy Turner, I can make two `doSomething` methods. 
A method that takes a String and another that takes a boolean.
The String method can then call the boolean method.
As follows:

```
void doSomething(String isSpecificRead) {
  doSomething(convertStringToBoolean(isSpecificReadString));
}

void doSomething(boolean isSpecificRead) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> So far, my solution has been to just suffix the type to the parameter.
>   But I don't like this solution.

Strongly typed language as Java works in this way.
 
Variables cannot change their type at runtime.
You have to accept the language constraints.

Converted a data from a type into another type within a method may create this issue. 
But your actual solution is rather fine.
The intention is clear and you kept a natural name for the target variable.

You indeed added the type suffix only for the input that will be converted (temporary/intermediary variable), not for the output that will be used in the next statement(s).